# Error message even though program is running

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have exported a runnable executable jar file from Eclipse, and I am able to run it and everything seems to work, but when I close down the program I get an error telling me the jar file cant be executed.

Can anyone tell me why this is? It's not so much of a problem, I am just curious to why it can tell me it can't be ran, when I just used the program..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: While exporting, which option did you choose for `Library handling` ?

Comment: How did you pachaged the jar file? The error log should be helpful also.

Comment: Check whether you have checked or unchecked the below two options
"Export Class files with compile errors"
"Export class files with compile warnings"

Comment: I think I solved it by checking for Package required libraries into generated jar. Thanks a lot!

Comment: CORRECTION:
I had written System.exit(1) instead of System.exit(0) when closing the program. I suspect that is what caused the problem.